# How to apply filters if editing specific template

Tags: customization, tinymce

I am using the following code to add custom styles to the content editor:

```
/* Customize editor */
function mce_mod( $init ) {
    $style_formats = array (
        array( 'title' => 'Gold Heading 1', 'block' => 'h1', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#d5b65b' ) ),
        array( 'title' => 'Gold Heading 2', 'block' => 'h2', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#d5b65b' ) ),
        array( 'title' => 'Gold text', 'inline' => 'span', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#d5b65b' ) )
    );
    $init['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_mod');

function mce_add_buttons( $buttons ){
    array_splice( $buttons, 1, 0, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'mce_add_buttons' );

function wp_editor_fontsize_filter( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'fontsizeselect');
    return $buttons;
}    
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'wp_editor_fontsize_filter');

function customize_text_sizes($initArray) {
    $initArray['fontsize_formats'] = "10px 11px 12px 13px 14px 15px 16px 17px 18px 19px 20px 21px 22px 23px 24px 25px 26px 27px28px 29px 30px 32px";
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'customize_text_sizes');
```

This will add dropdown menus to the Content Editor for font size and custom styles but I want it to apply only when editing the Home Page or a specific page template.

I tried wrapping the code with `is_front_page()` and `is_page_template('index.php')` like

```
function mce_add_buttons( $buttons ){
    if( is_page_template('index.php') ) :
        array_splice( $buttons, 1, 0, 'styleselect' );
        return $buttons;
    endif;
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'mce_add_buttons' );
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: is this in the classic post editor? Note that you can't know this when creating a new post as no page template has been selected yet. You'd need to save and refresh the page for any PHP based solution to work, otherwise it wouldn't show when you change the page template selection, and it wouldn't be hidden when you deselected a page template either. You could also cheat the system by selecting a page template with fonts, applying the formatting you wanted, then changing it back. These MCE filters also won't work in the block editor or page builders

Comment: This is for a site using the classic post editor.